# Getting 200 response, but not showing json value

Tags: json, swift, networking, urlsession

[image]I have wrote a networking request using the "wordsapi", and I am getting a 200 status, but the response I am receiving is not in json.

My code builds, and runs I just need the response in json.

```
    let wordsAPI = 
    "https://wordsapiv1.p.mashape.com/words/money/synonyms"
    let wordsAPIEndPoint = NSURL(string: wordsAPI)
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: wordsAPIEndPoint! as 
     URL)

    request.setValue("mapkey", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Mashape-Key")
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    let session = URLSession.shared

    let synonymResponse = session.dataTask(with: request as 
     URLRequest) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if let resp = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
           print(resp)
        }
     }
     synonymResponse.resume()
```

//response I am receiving

```
    { Status Code: 200, Headers {
    "Accept-Ranges" =     (
    bytes
    );
    "CF-RAY" =     (
     "4d4d9aacabdccf5c-IAD"
    );
    Connection =     (
    "keep-alive"
    );
    "Content-Length" =     (
    30
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
    "application/json; charset=utf-8"
     );Date =     (
    "Fri, 10 May 2019 17:24:00 GMT"
      );
```

I need my response to be in json for the synonyms of whatever value I set as my endpoint. In this case it is "money"

Comment: `data` has your JSON data.

Comment: FYI - do not use `NSURL` or `NSMutableURLRequest` in Swift. Use `URL` and `URLRequest`.

Comment: Do `String(data:data!, encoding: .utf8)` and attach the value

Comment: @rmaddy when I try and set data as? HTTPURLResponse and print resp, I receive an error "Value 'resp' was defined but never used; consider replacing with boolean test" and "Expression implicitly coerced from 'Data?' to 'Any'"

Comment: You need to update your question with your attempted code.

Comment: these are not errors , it's warnings and you should not cast `data` to `HTTPURLResponse ` because it will fail and it make no sense to

Comment: @Jazzin I get 401 response code and ["message": Key doesn't exists] json

Comment: @RajeshKumarR I see that now. I had to change request to var not a let variable. Also, I had to input my MapKey. Now the response is Optional("{\"word\":\"money\",\"synonyms\":[]}") which I am still not seeing the synonyms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `data` var in completion that contains the received json data

```
let wordsAPI = "https://wordsapiv1.p.mashape.com/words/money/synonyms"
let wordsAPIEndPoint = URL(string: wordsAPI)
var request = URLRequest(url: wordsAPIEndPoint!) 
request.setValue("mapkey", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Mashape-Key")
request.httpMethod = "GET"

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    guard let data = data else { return }
    let res = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self,from:data)
    print(res.synonyms)
}.resume()
```

---

```
struct Root:Codable {
  let word:String
  let synonyms:[String]
}
```

Comment: also make sure this key here `request.setValue("mapkey", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Mashape-Key")` is valid ???? `https://docs.rapidapi.com/docs/keys ` required a valid key so replace before you run

Comment: Optional("{\"word\":\"money\",\"synonyms\":[]}")
is the response I receive now, but no list of the synonyms.

Comment: try another word and see

Comment: It is valid Json, just need to get rid of the backslashes, to retrieve values.

Comment: "Instance method 'decode(_:from:)' requires that 'Root' conform to 'Decodable', and "Use of undeclared type 'codable'"

Comment: Thank you Very much. I have been using swift for about 3 months so trying to figure out everything. I appreciate it